# How to subscibe array of channels Node + Redis

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, redis

I am trying to subscibe array of channels like this:

```
socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
    console.log(data.channel);
    socket.join(data.channel);
    redisClient.subscribe(data.channel);
  });
```

`data.channel` returns json array like this:

```
[ 'chanel1',
  'chanel2',
  'chanel5',
  'chanel6',
  'chanel7',
  'chanel9',
  'chanel11',
  'chanel12',
  'chanel132',
  '$2y$10$wGlbS2Hv/pmDnt1Evg0u8epvDClAaEqvt6GqrQBPrECjJRbZe71Ge' ]
```

I am able to subscibe one channel but not multiple... Why this don't work?

Comment: which library are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to channels one by one:

```
// ...where "channels" is the array of channel names
channels.forEach(function(channel) {
    redisClient.subscribe(channel);
});
```